# Measure similarity of two images in Java or ImageMagick

Tags: java, compare, imagemagick, png, similarity

I have two different algorithms that take an image as input. The image has polygons of different colors. The algorithm "simplifies" these polygons (so that they have less corners and edges) and removes polygons, which are too small.

These two algorithms work differently and I want to know which one is actually better in terms of which one is closer to the original picture. I came across [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images#Java) but that is not quite what I was looking for.

These two images

[image: image 1] , [image: image 2]

should have a similarity of 50%, but according to that algorithm their similarity is 80%.

I also found a tool called [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) that can compare two images. But I am not sure what the meaning of the outputs is and how I can use them to solve my problem.

Comment: For those images, the 100% of both the blue and green channels are equal, while 50% of the red channel is equal. So 80 (or rather 83) % equal makes sense? Might not be what you were looking for though... ;-)

Comment: I know but I need a way to measure similarity in terms of which pixels were kept and which were changed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use ImageMagick like this to compare your two images:

```
compare -metric ae a.png b.png null:
1161
```

or, the longer form using `convert`

```
convert -metric ae a.png b.png -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
1161
```

The `-metric ae` means *"tell me the absolute error"*, i.e. the number of pixels that differ between the two images. In this case, the answer is 1161, which is exactly half the pixels, i.e. 50%.

If you specifically want 50% output, you can do the maths on the image dimensions with ImageMagick like this, if you use `bash`:

```
n=$(compare -metric ae a.png b.png null:)
identify -format "%[fx:$n*100/(w*h)]" a.png
```

or the longer form, using `convert`:

```
n=$(compare -metric ae a.png b.png null:)
convert -format "%[fx:$n*100/(w*h)]" a.png info:
50
```

If you are dealing with `jpg` images (and therefore lossy compression and artefacts) rather than `png` images, you may want to add in a `fudge factor` of a few percent, using the `-fuzz` parameter to allow almost identical pixels to count as being the same:

```
convert -fuzz 10% -metric ae ....
```

If you are unfortunate enough to have to use Windows, the way to do the above is arcane and unintelligible, but looks like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,*" %%G in ('convert -metric ae a.png b.png -compare -format "%%w %%h %%[distortion]" info:') DO set /a percent=(%%I * 100) /(%%G * %%H)
echo %percent%
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, looks very promising. I don't understand the n=$ part though.. I use the Windows prompt

Comment: `n=$(...)` means set tne variable `n` to the result (i.e. the output) of running the command inside the parentheses. So, in your example, `n` gets the value `1161`. It's a `Unix bash` feature - there is a Windows equivalent - I'll find it for you.

Comment: It's here... http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html  So, you would need to do something like... `FOR /F  %%G IN ('compare -metric ae a.png b.png null:') DO @SET n=%%G`

Comment: I worked out the awful Windows-y way of doing this, please see updated answer.

Comment: thank you, it worked. Yeah unfortunatly it has to be on windows -.-

Comment: I keep getting a results of 0 when I try "identify -format "%[fx:$n*100/(w*h)]" a.png". I ensure the two diffed images are different, and I do get a pixel difference in the "n=$(compare -metric ae a.png b.png null:)" line - Could someone please help? @MarkSetchell

Comment: I'm using ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 here and it seems `compare` outputs to **stderr** instead of stdout when used with the parameters in this answer, so to capture the output in $n, we must do:
`n=$(compare -metric ae a.png b.png null: 2>&1)`